# How to install LCD Touch display driver on ubuntu server 20.04 [rbPi 3B)

Tags: server, raspberrypi

How to install [LCD 3.5 touch](http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display) driver on ubuntu 20.04 installed on Raspberry Pi 3B?
I already tried to Install the driver provided, but here is what i got.

```
sudo ./LCD35-show
grep: /boot/cmdline.txt: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/boot/cmdline.txt': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbturbo.conf': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/boot/overlays/': Not a directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/boot/overlays/tft35a.dtbo': No such file or directory
grep: /boot/cmdline.txt: No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbturbo.conf': No such file or directory
2021
need to update touch configuration
dpkg: error processing archive ./xserver-xorg-input-evdev_1%3a2.10.6-1+b1_armhf.deb (--install):
 package architecture (armhf) does not match system (arm64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ./xserver-xorg-input-evdev_1%3a2.10.6-1+b1_armhf.deb
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf': No such file or directory
reboot now
Connection to 172.xx.x.xxx closed by remote host.
Connection to 172.xx.x.xxx closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

The problem is:

```
dpkg: error processing archive ./xserver-xorg-input-evdev_1%3a2.10.6-1+b1_armhf.deb (--install):
 package architecture (armhf) does not match system (arm64)
```

You see the driver is for armhf not arm64.

Comment: Okay, but is there any solution to this?

Comment: Yes the solution is to reflash the sdcard with the armhf version of the os.